# Use of *ed* and the end of word

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What are the uses of *ed* at the end of word?

e.g.

Named

Unprecedented

chaired

loved

annoyed

Dreamed

Also which sentence is correct? Using *ed* or without *ed*?

Please let me know which input to be *considered*

Or

Please let me know which input to be *consider*

Comment: Learn what is *[past participle](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/pastpartterm.htm)* The question is too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The most common use of the suffix '-**ed**' is to conjugate a verb to the past tense - eg:

*present tense*: They **lift** the object together.

*past tense*: They **lifted** the object together.

It can also be used to turn certain words into adjectives - eg:

*noun*: **concert**

*adjective*: **concerted**

*verb (present tense)*: **bless**

*adjective (as well as past tense of verb)*: **blessed**

In regard to your examples, neither are quite correct, but small changes could make either option viable:

Please let me know which input to consider.

*or*

Please let me know which input should be considered.